# How to do a "Where filter" using Loopback 4 explorer

Tags: swagger, loopbackjs

I'm trying to use the filter object in Loopback 4 to do a where clause, let's say I have a model named city and I want to filter the cities based on the name.

How you that filter look like in Loopback 4 explorer?

Here is what I have:

```
{
  "where": {"name":"Orlando"},
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 10,
  "order": [
    "string"
  ]  
}
```

This will produce the following Request URL:

**http://127.0.0.1:3000/cities?filter[offset]=0&filter[limit]=10**

I want to produce:
**http://127.0.0.1:3000/cities?filter[where][name]=Orlando&filter[offset]=0&filter[limit]=10**

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: Filter screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This is s known bug in Loopback 4.x due too a known bug/limitation of swagger-ui and swagger-js. See the corresponding discussions on Loopback's Github:

- [REST API to find models using a filter](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/pull/1679)
- [Filter where, fields, and order are not supported](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2208)

And the corresponding issue for the swagger-js:

- [Support deep objects for query parameters with deepObject style](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1385)

Comment: Is this now fixed? Thanks.